# Send headers from the post via webpack proxy

Tags: angular, rest, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Hi i have a request that i want to send via proxy to handle CORS but unfortunatelly when i use proxy, headers are dissapearing.

```
  postOrder(){
    this.http.post('/payu/order',this.request, {
      headers:{
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization" : "Bearer 8a424394-36aa-47a0-ac8c-5f48304e25aa"
      }
    }).subscribe(response => console.log(response))
  }
```

this is my post

```
{
  "/payu/order": {
    "target": "https://secure.payu.com/api/v2_1/orders",
    "changeOrigin": true,
  }

}
```

And there is **proxy.conf.json**

I have found that headers inside post are not being sent by proxy so the walk around is to send headers inside proxy like that:

```
  "/payu/order": {
    "target": "https://secure.payu.com/api/v2_1/orders",
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization" : "Bearer 1c208fe3-072f-4de5-a681-6a179952cafe"
    }
  }
```

Is there any way to make proxy accept headers from the post, or set Authorization header inside proxy as a parameter? Or maybe there is any other way to get rid of CORS problem than using proxy.

Comment: It should work without mentioning inside the proxy configuration, I have tried this.

Comment: are you getting response of : `{error: "invalid_token", error_description: "Invalid access token"}` or just log in prompt?